# ERROR: Communications link failure in MYSQL using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am developing an application where persistence is done via JPA and Hibernate 4.2.3. everything is working normally the first moment.

However when you spend a certain time (in my case one day) application aprensenta the following error.

```
ERROR: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 259.217.434 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.

Abaixo deixo meu persistence.xml...

<persistence-unit name="amh_sys" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

<properties>

<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amh_sys" />

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />

<property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />

<property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="true" />

</properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I tried to configure using C3P0 connection pool, however had the same error ... Below configuration of C3P0.

```
<!-- Important -->

<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

I can force the error by changing the date on your computer, because MySQL gets the same date as a reference. I can not solve this problem, I hope someone here had the same problem trying to share your solution applied.

Felipe.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL server will timeout the connect if it has been idle for too long. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html You can do use a scheduled query within the timeout to keep the connect active or re-establish the connection by closing and re-creating the EntityManager